# Uploadify giving HTTP Error (403) while saving files direct to Amazon S3

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, uploadify, http-status-code-403

Here is the following code of mine [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com), to upload files direct to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/):

```
<html>
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="uploadify.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                        'requeueErrors' : true,
                        'fileDataName'  : 'file',
                        'method'        : 'post',
                        'formData'      : { 
                                            'key': 'uploads/${filename}', 
                                            'AWSAccessKeyId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',    
                                            'bucket': 'mybucket', 
                                            'acl': 'authenticated-read', 
                                            'policy': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
                                            'signature': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
                                             'Content-Type': 'text' 
                                           },
                         'fileObjName'  : 'file',
                         'cancelImg'    : 'cancel.png',
                         'uploader'     : 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
                         'swf'          : 'uploadify.swf',
                         'auto'         : false,
                         'fileType'     : 'text',
                         'onUploadStart': function(file)
                                           {
                                                console.log('Attempting to upload: ' + file.name);
                                            },
                         'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response)
                                            {
                                                 alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
                                            }
                       });
              });
          </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <form>
           <p><input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" /></p>
           <p><a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload')">Upload Files</a></p>
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When I try to upload the files to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), got the following error: **HTTP Error (403)**
Please help where the problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am also uploading files on Amazon S3 with uploadify, i suggest you to try implementing my strategy

First i upload files on my server using uploadify then upload them to Amazon S3 and after uploading i delete the uploaded files from my server,its an easy approach

Comment: Thanks Syed for the tip. Somehow the thing you are mentioned that is not my requirement (My requirement is to upload direct to S3).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: It looks like I'm using an older version of uploadify, not sure how accurate my answer is now. Will update soon**

I was looking for some help for another problem but I thought I stop and help you a bit.

I see you have set the amazon url in the uploader parameter:

```
'uploader'     : 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
'swf'          : 'uploadify.swf',
```

I have something different which works perfectly, I also see in other examples that uploader links to the uploadify.swf and the script to the path where you wish to upload.

like this:

```
'uploader'  : '/resources/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : '<?php echo $uploadPath; ?>',
```

Upload path variable being (in my code):

```
$uploadPath = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/' . $bucket;
```

Here is a complete example of what I have and which works:

```
$('#file_mainfile').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '<?php echo WPDEPOSIT_URL; ?>/resources/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '<?php echo $uploadPath; ?>',
    'cancelImg' : '<?php echo WPDEPOSIT_URL; ?>/resources/images/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '<?php echo $fileFolder; ?>',
    'auto'      : true,
    'fileExt'   : '*.zip',
    'buttonText': '<?php _e('Upload .zip', WPD_SHOPPER_NAME); ?>',
    'method'    : 'post',
    'fileDataName'  : 'file',
    'auto'          : 'true',
    'scriptData' : {
            "AWSAccessKeyId"                                : "<?php echo $amazonClass->AWS_ACCESS_KEY; ?>",
            "key"                       : "${filename}",
            "acl"                       : "public-read",
            "policy"                    : "<?php echo $policy; ?>",
            "signature"                 : "<?php echo $signature; ?>",
            "success_action_status"                         : "201",
            "key"                       : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("<?php echo $folder; ?>${filename}")),
            "fileext"                   : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("")),
            "Filename"                  : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(""))
    },
    'onError'     : function (event,ID,fileObj, response) {

    },
    'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            var filePath = $(response).find("location").text();
            displayMessage('success', 'file_mainfile', '<?php _e('Successfully uploaded to Amazon S3 server.', WPD_QA_NAME); ?>', filePath);
            window.wpds_thumbnail = filePath;

    }
});
```

I upload everything in a seperate folder, that's why you see a folder variable in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hope it will work, somehow I'm using ColdFusion instead of PHP, somehow I'm familar of PHP as well. Currently I'm on other important development task. I will try soon your exapmle and let you know what will be the outcome. :)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right about the `script` to upload file to S3, but I think that was supported in the old version of Uploadify, have a look on the documentation of uploadify you can't find `script` Option any more: [uploadify documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/). If it is possible whenever you got time to do so, than kindly send me the version of uploadify to download(exactly which you are using). May it help. Thanks again, and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used following way to solve.

1. I am using ubuntu, so using wireshark I found the error xml which s3 was returning. This error gave idea about what is going wrong.
2. Error told me that acl is already in policy document, so it should not be n formData. Check if you have the same.